terser form to select the first row for a keyed table
Suppose I have a table
q) t:([]
    name:`c`c`c`w`w;
    id:1 1 1 2 1;
    c:2 4 5 4 3
 );

q)show t;
name id c
---------
c    1  2
c    1  4
c    1  5
w    2  4
w    1  3

and I would like to get the first row given the composite grouping of name and id.
Since I only have one column I can do
q)select first c by name,id from t
name id c
---------
c    1  2
w    2  4
w    1  3

which gives me the required result. However, suppose I have several other columns (apart from name, id, c) making it inconvenient to type
select first c, first col1, first col2, ...,first colN by name,id from t 

Is there something terser?

Use fby https://code.kx.com/q/ref/fby/#tables
q)select from t where i=(first;i) fby ([] name; id)
name id c
---------
c    1  2
w    2  4
w    1  3
q)


Awesome. Could you point me to where fby for multiple columns, e.g., fby ([]name;id) is documented?

Last example on link I shared above.

You can also do this quite tersely with indexing, by keying your table on the columns you are interested in. This leverages the fact that in the case of non-unique keys, the first match is returned:
q){distinct[key x]#x:2!x}t
name id| c
-------| -
c    1 | 2
w    2 | 4
w    1 | 3


There are 2 ways I would approach that:

specify a list of grouping columns (in your case, name and id) and use a functional select:

g:`name`id
?[t;();{x!x}g;()]


use xgroup and select the first element of each grouped columns:

g:`name`id
{first each x} each xgroup[g;t]

For example, you define you table as
t:([] name:`c`c`c`w`w;id:(1;1;1;2;1);c:(2;4;5;4;3);d:til 5)

The result will be:
name id| c d
-------| ---
c    1 | 2 0
w    2 | 4 3
w    1 | 3 4

The advantage of the second approach is that, with a simple twist, you can choose which function to apply to aggregation, as follows:
{[f;dt] f each dt}[avg;] each xgroup[g;t]
{[f;dt] f each dt}[first;] each xgroup[g;t]
{[f;dt] f each dt}[last;] each xgroup[g;t]


For small tables you could do the following
q)select by name,id from reverse t
name id| c
-------| -
c    1 | 2
w    1 | 3
w    2 | 4

When you use select by name,id from t it will select the last row for each key, and by reversing the table first it will ult in exactly what you are looking for. However, reverse is expensive on large tables, so Rian's solution is probably best.
